# Data Explorer's stored queries should have a slug in URLs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer, permalink, slug

Links to stored queries should have a slug like SO question links: e.g. http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/734/how-long-until-i-get-the-generalist-badge

Comment: working on it, so many changes

Answer (score 2):

This was a fairly hairy change, we now have slugs for "saved queries" and "queries" not the slug is ignored (like here) and generated on render.

Comment: There should be a slug also at 'save query' and 'download results'.

Comment: At the moment when slugs are "not available" they are provided as "undefined". Can this be cleaned up so when a useful slug is not available, nothing is added to the URL.